# Squish for testing GUI developed using ExtJS

Tags: extjs, casperjs, automated-tests, gui-testing, squish

I am looking for automated testing tools to test a webpage heavily written using ExtJS. Initially I was using casperJS/phantomJS. Since, those tests work best in a CI environment and are super-light and easy to code. But I found a limitation that casperJs does not support TrifleJS for IE testing. It only supports phantomJS(chrome and safari) and slimerJS(firefox).
I need to test our web-app on IE9, IE10 and IE11 too. Squish seems to be very flexible and well-developed. I want to know whether it is suitable for testing the ExtJS web-app.

Thanks

Comment: Did you consider [Siesta](http://www.bryntum.com/products/siesta/)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But right now I have a license for Squish which I can use. I don't have a license for Siesta. And I don't want to purchase another tool.

Answer (score 0):

According to the matrix [at this link](http://download.froglogic.com/public/Squish.pdf) Squish does support ExtJS framework. Of course main problem of testing ExtJS apps is that all the element IDs are dynamically generated and one cannot rely on these for UI testing. However Squish [provides XPath-based search](http://doc.froglogic.com/squish/latest/ugs-webapi.html#ugsweb-xpath) that can be used instead.
I'm actively evaluating Squish for our ExtJS 4.2.x based web app so in a while if you interested I would be able to provide more insights but it does look very promising especially since you can use Eclipse-based plugin to build your tests visually